# How to conduct Topic Modeling on lyrics bigrams?

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I'd like to conduct topic modeling on lyrics data drawn from the Billboard100 dataset. So far, I've built dataframe of bigrams with Track ID.

```
    # Create bigram with lyrics
bigram<-ID_lyrics %>% 
  unnest_tokens(bigram, lyrics, token = "ngrams", n = 2)
```

An example of the bigram dataframe.[image: bigram data frame]

However, I encountered error when trying to use LDA() on the bigram data.

```
x <- as.simple_triplet_matrix(bigram) 
result<-LDA(x,k=10)
```

How do I turn the current bigram data into a sparse matrix with 0 & 1 for each track?

Comment: maybe??  `Matrix::fac2sparse(bigram$bigram)` ?

Comment: Thanks! Tried Matrix, but the LDA() returns "Null"